# Magento Suddenly Started Throwing Errors: No changes made recently

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Magento started throwing errors yesterday, for no appearant reason. No change have been made to the files and nothing has been added to the site. Any advice? The magento version is 1.4 I have included the error log below.

Thanks

Error Log

```
a:4:{i:0;s:70:"Mage registry key "_singleton/aitsys/rewriter_observer" already exists";i:1;s:2732:"#0 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(192): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(446): Mage::register('_singleton/aits...', false)
#2 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1209): Mage::getSingleton('aitsys/rewriter...')
#3 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('resource_get_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(167): Mage::dispatchEvent('resource_get_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(265): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName('core/store_grou...')
#6 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(247): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->getTable('store_group')
#7 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Collection/Abstract.php(137): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->getMainTable()
#8 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Collection/Abstract.php(174): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract->getMainTable()
#9 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Collection/Abstract.php(117): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract->_initSelect()
#10 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1208): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Group))
#11 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1241): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_mysql4/sto...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Group))
#12 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(460): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/store_grou...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Group))
#13 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/store_grou...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Group))
#14 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#15 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(536): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#16 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(393): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#17 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(299): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#18 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:59:"/shop/specials/enphase-ac-extension-cable-12-feet-d380.html";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/shop/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd throw away your assumptions about "nothing has changed".  Due to Magento's various caches, it can be hours, or even days before a new code/configuration deployment actually shows an effect on the system.

Second, you're using a very out of date version of Magento.  This fact often coincides with a very "altered from it's default state" Magento.  This means there may not be a general answer to your problem, and only a developer investigating your exact system will be able to solve your problem.

Looking at your call stack, it appears when the `resource_get_tablename` event fires

```
#3 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('resource_get_ta...', Array)
```

that there's an observer configured configured with a model name that starts with `aitsys/rewriter...` (PHP cuts off the full alias name).

```
#2 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1209): Mage::getSingleton('aitsys/rewriter...')
```

Whenever Magento instantiates a singleton event observer (or any singleton model), it adds it to the registry, with a call to `Mage::register`.

```
#1 /home/solarcon/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(446): Mage::register('_singleton/aits...', false)
```

However, with your system, Magento thinks there's already an entry in the registry for that model/keyname

> Mage registry key "_singleton/aitsys/rewriter_observer" already exists

**HOWEVER**, in a stock Magento system, this should never happen, as `getSingleton` checks the registry before trying to instantiate a model

```
public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

This leads me to believe your core system has been altered.   Also, the name of the observer model (`aitsys/rewriter_observer`) comes from a well known (if notorious) extension provider named [AITOC](http://www.aitoc.com/).  They're notorious because they altered your code Magento system to implement some systems of their own, including their DRM-ish licensing system.  Given it's their extension causing this problem, you might have some luck reaching out to their support personal.

Given all that, it's doubtful someone will be able to come up with an answer here.  Hopefully the above information will help you (or your developer) debug this themselves.

Comment: Hi Alan,

Thanks for this insight. It looks like this was a module that was installed when the site went live over several years ago. It looks like the module stopped working. I removed the module files and manually cleared the Mage cache and everything started working normally except for what was used by that module. I guess now I need to talk the client on doing a new site with Shopify. The CE of magneto really is getting further and further behind.